# CUDA SASS to Cubin

Tags: cuda, nvcc

With CuObjDump SASS can be generated from Cubin file using 
`cuobjdump -sass <input file>`, But is there any way to convert the SASS back to Cubin.

Comment: The one word answer is, I believe, no.

Comment: If you are asking if there is a tool that will take code written in SASS and turn it into something that is executable, that would basically be a SASS assembler, and NVIDIA provides no such tools (the lowest NVIDIA supported toolchain is PTX), but you may want to take a look at [the maxas assembler](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "assemblers" provided as part of the official NVIDIA CUDA toolchain.  The NVIDIA toolchain can take CUDA C/C++, or PTX, and convert it to a cubin or other executable format.

However there are some community-developed assemblers:

Perhaps the most recent one at this time (probably the only one worth considering at this time) is [maxas](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas).

There also was an older one [asfermi](https://github.com/hyqneuron/asfermi) developed in the Fermi generation of CUDA GPUs.  I don't think it has been updated or maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that depending on the architecture (maxwell/kepler etc), you can use a community developed assembler/dissembler to convert the SASS back to Cubin. Here are some:

Maxas: https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas

KeplerAs: https://github.com/PAA-NCIC/PPoPP2017_artifact/tree/master/KeplerAs